# Excel Dropdownlist with pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Dropdown list but, instead of selecting a value and then have a picture appear on that or another cell, I want to directly select from a list of pictures. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think so, but it could probably be emulated with a normally hidden frame of image controls which is revealed when the drop-down list is activated. Another approach is to have a multi-page control where, when you need to make a selection, a page is shown which presents the user with a grid of clickable images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, I will try it :)